# $482$ people want to go by $30$ cars to a hotel. The cars can carry $4,19$ and $21$ people. Every car has to be full.

Tags: combinatorics

482 people want to go by 30 cars to a hotel. The cars can carry 4,19 and 21 people. Every car has to be full. How many cars do we need from each type? Give all the possibilities.

Can you give me a step by step answer?

Comment: $$4a+19b+21c=482$$ and $$a+b+c=30$$

Comment: I assume the people have to remain whole on this trip?

Comment: What seems to be the difficulty with this question? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$4a+19b+21c=482  \quad*$$
and 
$$a+b+c=30$$
replacing
$$c=30-a-b$$
in * gives $$17a+2b=148$$
the general solution of the latter is $$a=8+2k$$ and $$b=6-17k$$
$(k\in \mathbb Z)$. So $c$ is $$c=30-a-b=16+15k$$

Comment: What is k here?

Comment: $k$ ranges over Z...